# window pip install scrapy error "running build_ext error: [Error 5]"

Tags: scrapy

How can I avoid this error?

```
    running build_ext
    error: [Error 5]

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-zc67ii\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=g
etattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.c
lose();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admini~1
\appdata\local\temp\pip-pxb6xl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-extern
ally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admini~1\appdata\lo
cal\temp\pip-build-zc67ii\Twisted\

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing **Scrapy** on **Windows** can be a real struggle.

That's why the  [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#installing-scrapy) recommands to use [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/) for the scrapy installation. I think you should give it a try if you are working on **Windows**.

First you need to install Anaconda following this [tutorial](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-windows).

Then you just need to run this command `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`
 and you are good to go.

Comment: there is a anther way to avoid error with out install Anaconda?wish you answer,thanks agint

Comment: You still have installation errors ? What kind of error do you have ?

Comment: to install conda error "Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting menuinst (from conda)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda)
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)"

Comment: Try this: [Miniconda](https://conda.io/docs/install/quick.html) it's a light version of Anaconda

Comment: i try load the Miniconda many times,all with load failed, i will try later.thanks for your help.

Comment: it's failed where is a new error:    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'menuinst' distribution was not found an
d is required by conda

Comment: where is not anther way for the error? wish your Answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with that particular problem. I suggest you make another post for the conda experts on Stack Overflow. Hope you'll succeed

Comment: thanks all. i am succeed in my anther computer but i don't how to make it succee.The anther computer just run this command:pip install scrapy ,it work