# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h'

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, cmp

So i have been trying to install Scrapy for Python for the last couple of days. 
Trying anything i could think off and read everything i have come across with similar problems, but haven't been able to find a solution. 
So here is the code.

Thank you.

```
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\twisted
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\twisted\test
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 "-Ic:\users\karl holst\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include" "-Ic:\users\karl holst\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    raiser.c
    c:\users\karl holst\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include\pyconfig.h(222): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\karl holst\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\KARLHO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ylmjilcy\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KARLHO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hjzcemls-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KARLHO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ylmjilcy\Twisted\
```

edit - the code i have used is "pip install Scrapy"

Comment: If you are using Windows, scrapy recommends using Anaconda/Miniconda and the `conda-forge` channel: see [the installation guide](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows).

Comment: As said by @paul trmbrth  you should use `conda`. You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415065/window-pip-install-scrapy-error-running-build-ext-error-error-5)

Answer (score 5):

I could solve this problem by downloading and installing the latest Windows 10 SDK from this link:
https://software-download.microsoft.com/download/pr/19041.685.201201-2105.vb_release_svc_prod1_WindowsSDK.iso

and the basetsd.h file appeared in the following folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similiar issue involving Scrapy which also failed when it came to the Twisted part of the installation. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44867665/6845760) should still apply to your issue, it involves updating your SDK and making sure your `.exe` files are in the right location.

Got Scrapy installed in the end perfectly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try after installing Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266

Comment: Thank you but i fixed it by downloading anaconda, i dont know how to flag this as solved, but thank you for taking time to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Must have the most recent version of Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. In my case it was 2017.

It's like 6GB which is unfortunate because I feel like I get 20MB worth of use from it. But that's what is needed.

It can be downloaded with Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 0):

Deployed below components from VC++ installer. Then try pip install pandas. It worked for me.

C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.24)

MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)

MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ ARM build tools (v14.16)

MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ ARM64 build tools (v14.16)

MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.16)

MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (v14.16)

C++ 2019 Redistributable Update

C++ Clang Compiler for Windows (9.0.0)

C++ Clang-cl for v142 build tools (x64/x86)

C++ CMake tools for Windows

C++ Modules for v142 build tools (x64/x86 – experimental)